# Trouble getting NSString from NSDictionary key into UILabel

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel, nsdictionary

I'm attempting to put the value associated with the key called "duration" into a `UILabel` but I'm getting a blank or "(null)" result showing up in the `UILabel`.

My `NSDictionary` object with its keys seems to be logging as being full of the data and keys I think I want, as such:

The contents of this RecordingsStats are :

```
{
     "12:48:25 AM, April 25" = {
          FILEPATH = "/Users/brian/Library/Application  Support/iPhone  Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/97256A91-FC47-4353-AD01-15CD494060DD/Documents/12:48:25 AM, April 25.aif";  
    duration = "00:04"; 

applesCountString = 0;
```

...and so on.

Here's the code where I'm trying to put the `NSString` into the `UILabel`:

`cell.durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"]];`

I've also tried these other permutations:

`cell.durationLabel.text = [thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"];`

and I've also tried this tag-based approach:

```
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
 label.text = [[thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"] objectAtIndex:1];
```

and:

```
UILabel *label;
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
         label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

I've also tried creating a string from the key's paired value and see a "(null)" value or blankness using that too.

What am I missing? I assume it's something with the formatting of the string.  Thanks for looking!!

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where you're setting the text.  At the gdb prompt in your console, type po [thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"].  What do you see?

Comment: When I enter:  
po [thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"duration"] 

or when trying the suggested answer below:
po [stats objectForKey:@"duration"] 

I see: Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Comment: Actually now I see my string there. Thank you for that, though the answer below has me trying to nestle a dynamic key that is the truncated filename date key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be jumping the gun a bit but from the look of your log output your NSDictionary is set out as having **"12:48:25 AM, April 25"** as the key, with another `NSDictionary` as its value.

i.e.

```
"12:48:25 AM, April 25" => NSDictionary (
                              FILEPATH => (value)
                              duration => @"00:04"
                           )
```

etc.

What you need to do is: -

```
NSDictionary *stats = [thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"12:48:25 AM, April 25"];
cell.durationLabel.text = [stats objectForKey:@"duration"];
```

Comment: You're correct: I do have a dictionary filled with dictionaries, as I wanted each recording's stats to be accessible by its truncated date of origin string.  It now seems my problem is in putting in the code that inserts the dynamic key based upon the date key for each dictionary.  Right now I've got something like this returning errors:  NSDictionary *stats = [thisRecordingsStats objectForKey:@"%@",[[self.fileList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension]];  but I'll make this a new question.   THANKS for your time.